# Form action is not interrupted by "required" inputs

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have the following HTML code.

```js
function document_save_changes(){
 if (is_key_dirty == true){
  var elm = document.getElementById('set_doc_button');
  key_change_warning(elm, 'D');
  return;
 }
 if (document_save_warning('A') == false){
  return;
 }
 collect_nonkey_data();
 do_recaptcha();
}
```

```html
<form id="email_form">
 <div id="email_table" class="emltbl inbtop" style="margin:auto;">
  <div class="emlrow">
   <div class="emlcll">Name:</div>
   <div class="emlcll"><input class="email_input" type="text" name="email_1" id="email_1" placeholder="First and last name" required autocomplete="on" data-lpignore="true"/></div>
  </div>
  <div class="emlrow">
   <div class="emlcll">Email:</div>
   <div class="emlcll"><input class="email_input" type="email" name="email_2" id="email_2" placeholder="Return email address" required autocomplete="on" data-lpignore="true"/></div>
  </div>
  <div class="emlrow">
   <div class="emlcll">Messg:</div>
   <div class="emlcll"><textarea class="email_textarea" name="email_3" id="email_3" placeholder="Message to admin" required autocomplete="off"></textarea></div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div id="email_recaptcha" class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="key goes here"></div>
 <div><button id="set_doc_button" type="button" style="padding:0.3em 1em;" disabled="disabled" autocomplete="off" onclick="document_save_changes();" title="Submit changes to data">Submit Data</button></div>
</form>
```

My problem is that the "required" INPUT elements are not causing the form submission to fail when the INPUT elements are not filled properly. (For instance, by the `type="email"` INPUT element which requires special syntax.)

How do I make it so that the "required" INPUTs interrupt the form action if they are not filled in properly? Thanks.

Comment: because you're not submitting the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you're not submitting the form. Making a button at the last of type `button` doesn't make it a submit button. You'll have to specify the `type='submit'` explicitly to make a button submit the form.

And now to the second part,

If you're trying to submit the form from `JS` function. The HTML5 validation won't work.

Inshort they are only in action when form is submitted with a button of type submit inside that form. And if you do want to use a button of type `button` and submit the form with `JS`, you'll have to check for validation in your `JS` code.

And in your `JS` code you can use `checkValidity()` function on any form to check if it's a valid from or not and then run the other things accordingly

```js
var form = document.getElementById("email_form");

function document_save_changes() {
    //Do your things
    if (form.checkValidity()) {
        form.submit();
    } else {
        alert("Something worng yet")
    }

}
```

```html
<form id="email_form">
   <div id="email_table" class="emltbl inbtop" style="margin:auto;">
      <div class="emlrow">
         <div class="emlcll">Name:</div>
         <div class="emlcll"><input class="email_input" type="text" name="email_1" id="email_1" placeholder="First and last name" required autocomplete="on" data-lpignore="true"/></div>
      </div>
      <div class="emlrow">
         <div class="emlcll">Email:</div>
         <div class="emlcll"><input class="email_input" type="email" name="email_2" id="email_2" placeholder="Return email address" required autocomplete="on" data-lpignore="true"/></div>
      </div>
      <div class="emlrow">
         <div class="emlcll">Messg:</div>
         <div class="emlcll"><textarea class="email_textarea" name="email_3" id="email_3" placeholder="Message to admin" required autocomplete="off"></textarea></div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div id="email_recaptcha" class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="key goes here"></div>
   <div><button id="set_doc_button" type="button" style="padding:0.3em 1em;"  autocomplete="off" onclick="document_save_changes();" title="Submit changes to data">Submit Data</button></div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one

Use `button type='submit'` instead of `button`

```
<button id="set_doc_button" type="submit" style="padding:0.3em 1em;"  autocomplete="off" onclick="document_save_changes();" title="Submit changes to data">Submit Data</button>
```

and  remove `disabled="disabled"` after that your form will submit